# How do I "untaint" a variable?

Tags: perl, cgi

upto my knowledge once a variable is tainted, Perl won't allow  to use it in a system(), exec(), piped open, eval(), backtick command, or any function that affects something outside the program (such as unlink). So whats the process to untaint it?

Comment: Most of the Security chapter of Mastering Perl goes through this, and it's not just what's in perlsec. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a regular expression on the tainted variable to pull out the "safe" values:

> Sometimes you have just to clear your data's taintedness. Values may be untainted by using them as keys in a hash; otherwise the only way to bypass the tainting mechanism is by referencing subpatterns from a regular expression match. Perl presumes that if you reference a substring using $1, $2, etc., that you knew what you were doing when you wrote the pattern.

Don't ignore this warning though:

> That means using a bit of thought--don't just blindly untaint anything, or you defeat the entire mechanism. It's better to verify that the variable has only good characters (for certain values of "good") rather than checking whether it has any bad characters. That's because it's far too easy to miss bad characters that you never thought of.

[Perlsec: Laundering and Detecting Tainted Data](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html#Laundering-and-Detecting-Tainted-Data)

Comment: +1 for the appropriate standard documentation. I want to add that the use of `$1` and friends is not mandatory, a match expression with captures returns a list of scalars that are untainted, too. Example: `perl -T -MDevel::Peek -e'Dump [$ARGV[0] =~ /(\d+)/g]' 'The Fiorina "Fury" 161 Class C Work Correctional Unit (reg. 12037154) at one point maintained thousands of double-Y chromosome maximum risk prisoners but in 2179 supported twenty-two inmates and three custodians.'`

Answer (score 6):

[`use Untaint`](https://metacpan.org/module/Untaint):

> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> This module is used to launder data which has been tainted by using
>   the `-T` switch to be in taint mode. This can be used for CGI scripts
>   as well as command line scripts. The module will untaint scalars,
>   arrays, and hashes. When laundering an array, only array elements
>   which are tainted will be laundered.
>
> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
> use Untaint;
>
> my $pattern = qr(^k\w+);
>
> my $foo = $ARGV[0];
>
> # Untaint a scalar
> if (is_tainted($foo)) {
>         print "\$foo is tainted. Attempting to launder\n";
>         $foo = untaint($pattern, $foo);
> }else{
>         print "\$foo is not tainted!!\n";
> }
> ```

Comment: Unfortunately the Untaint CPAN distribution depends on the Taint CPAN distribution (without specifying the dependency properly), and that distribution fails its test suite: http://matrix.cpantesters.org/?dist=Taint+0.09
So one can assume that Untaint is broken, too.